# Upload business with paid subscriptions

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm building a website with Reactjs,

the website consists of publishing businesses that customers upload themselves but with a paid subscription, every 30 days the payment will be renewed or the business that they have uploaded will be cancelled.

My headless CMS is now on Wordpress but I'm thinking of moving it to Strapi to make it more scalable and have much more control,

Is it possible for Strapi to accept this data ingestion from a third party? And if with Strapi I can implement that the subscription is paid by Stripe, have everything connected.

My idea is that the client uploads the images of the business, the description, etc. And after he fills in his data, he will be taken to a payment screen, where he will pay the annual or monthly fee.

After all this process, I would enter to accept or reject those businesses that are accepted.

Can you guide me a little with the tools that you recommend, if I should or should not use these.

I am open to your answers.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [this Subscriptions guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions) to get started. Then, you can use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to manage state in your application and keep everything synced up with Stripe. [Here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks) is a more subscription-oriented webhook guide.